# Angular6/Karma Unit Testing - How to include external JS library (AOS)?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm using [AOS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aos)  (Animate on scroll library - an external JS library) in angular 6 project and it is loaded to the project in following way.

```
import AOS from 'aos';

ngAfterViewInit() {
    AOS.init();
  }
```

I need to load this external JS library to the Angular Unit Test Component in order to run the angular unit test. How to do that? I tried following way but it doesn't work. (I believe it's because AOS is not a component per se)

```
import AOS from 'aos';

describe("SampleComponent", () => {
  let component: SampleComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SampleComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [SampleComponent],
      imports: [
        FormsModule,
        RouterTestingModule,
        AOS
      ],
      providers:[]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SampleComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it("should create", () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include under script section in angular.json.

```
"scripts": ["src/app/lib/path/xxxx.js"]
```